# Make multiple iframes drag, resize and minimize like a regular window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm working on a Dashboard for work where I have multiple `iframes` open on one web page, each `iframe` having a different site. I have been able to get the `div`'s holding the `iframes` to resize and drag, but I cant for the life of me get it to minimize when I press the top left image. Here's what I have so far:

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(function () {"use strict"; 
 $("#framewrap") .resizable() .draggable();
});
```

```css
.body_padding {
    padding: 16px;
}
#framewrap {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    background-color: #277099;
    width: 512px;
    height: 90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 16px -2px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 16px -2px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    position: absolute;
}
#frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="framewrap">
          <span style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: small; font-style: normal; font-weight: 100;">Window 1</span>
          <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/minimize_window.png" alt="" width="18" height="18" align="right"/>
          <iframe id="frame" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 
<script src="js/main.js"></script
</body>
```

The idea is that I can press the minimize button on the right, and it changes the height and width of the wrapper `div` to a height of `90px` and a width of `256px`. I'd need to have multiple `iframes` open at once in one page that can individually move, resize, and minimize as needed. Any help is appreciated Thanks!!

Comment: First, you should avoid using ids if you need to have several iframe ;) Use classes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend this a bit for multiple windows, I switched a few of your ID based elements to class based elements.  You also had jQuery included a few times and I simplified that.

I think this should get you going.  It is basically a simple toggle of a minimize class on your container.

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".framewrap").resizable().draggable();
  $(".framewrap .actionIcon").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".framewrap").toggleClass("min");
  });
});
```

```css
.body_padding {
  padding: 16px;
}

.framewrap {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  background-color: #277099;
  width: 512px;
  height: 90px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 16px -2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 16px -2px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}

.framewrap span {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: small;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.framewrap .actionIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-image: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/minimize_window.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.framewrap.min {
  height: 90px !important;
  width: 256px !important;
}

.framewrap.min .actionIcon {
  background-image: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/maximize_window.png);
}

.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div>
  <div class="framewrap">
    <span>Window 1</span>
    <span class="actionIcon"></span>
    <iframe class="frame" src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Jon, This worked perfectly i'm able to have multiple frames working independently like a charm. now is there any way to change to zindex for the frame i currently have clicked? many of the windows overlap awkwardly

Comment: @xpt What version of jquery would you like? Still version 2? I ask as it is a bit out of date now.

Comment: @xpt Thanks, it was just that one of the libraries was being called via http rather than https

Comment: Perfect now. Thanks JonSG!